# Check log messages for file system errors

Tags: linux, fedora-13, logging

Fedora 13
    kernal 2.6.34.6-54.fc13.i686
    HP Notebook dv6000 4 years old

I have been having a problem starting my notebook. I get the BIOS screen. But before I get to the GRUB loader menu option. I get a blank screen that saids "Cannot find operating system". It always does this on the first boot, the second boot always starts without a problem.

I am just wondering what messages I can check in the /var/log/ to check if there was any errors maybe with the hard disk or file system?

I have all these and not sure which one I should check:

```
anaconda.log          btmp           dkms_autoinstaller  maillog-20100919   pm-suspend.log   setroubleshoot    vbox-install.log
anaconda.program.log  btmp-20100904  dmesg               maillog-20100926   ppp              spooler           wpa_supplicant.log
anaconda.storage.log  ConsoleKit     dmesg.old           messages           prelink          spooler-20100905  wpa_supplicant.log-20100904
audit                 cron           gdm                 messages-20100905  samba            spooler-20100913  wtmp
boot.log              cron-20100905  lastlog             messages-20100913  secure           spooler-20100919  wtmp-20100913
boot.log-20100905     cron-20100913  mail                messages-20100919  secure-20100905  spooler-20100926  Xorg.0.log
boot.log-20100913     cron-20100919  maillog             messages-20100926  secure-20100913  sssd              Xorg.0.log.old
boot.log-20100919     cron-20100926  maillog-20100905    ntpstats           secure-20100919  tallylog          Xorg.9.log
boot.log-20100926     cups           maillog-20100913    pm-powersave.log   secure-20100926  vbox              yum.log
```

Comment: You want to look into `/var/log/messages` for I/O errors. But could it be that your BIOS has problems and doesn't find your harddrive at a cold boot (my desktop computer has that problem)?

Comment: Examine `boot.log` @ant2009